# Shape oblique bottom border of a div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm building a simple website, and on its landing page I need two backgrounds. For that, I'm using two divs, one on top of the other. So far so good.

The problem is, I want the bottom border of the first div (or the top border of the second) to be oblique. This is a sketch of what I want to do:

[image: Sketch]

[image: Layout I need to follow]

Any idea how to accomplish this?

I found this article, but it only works with floating elements, and it doesn't seem stable at all.

http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Thanks in advance!

html:

```
div class="main-container" id="main-container1">
    //all kinds of stuff
</div>

<div class="main-container" id="main-container2">
      //all kinds of stuff
</div>
```

css:

```
#main-container1{
    background: url(../img/background1.jpg);
    background-position:center;


}

#main-container2{
    background: url(../img/background2.jpg);
    background-position:center;


}
```

Comment: please provide the code you have so far. Also CSS Shapes (the article you linked) is not implemented yet.

Comment: Does anything need to “happen” with those elements, resp. their backgrounds – like any kind of scrolling effects, dynamic sizes or whatever? Or to phrase it differently, what is stopping you from using the “easy” solution of just having that “oblique” border simply be part of the background image of the second div itself, by making it have a triangular transparent part …?

Comment: the second background is supposed to be a pattern, so I'd have to modify it to cope with your solution. but it's an idea.I'd have to modify the div hierarchy slightly as well right?

Comment: why can't you combine the 2 background images into 1 image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best way to do this

```css
.second {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    transform:skewY(20deg);
    background:orange;
    margin-top:-100px;
    border:2px solid green;
}

.holder{
    width:500px;
    height:800px;
    background:grey;
}

.second p{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:200px;
    transform:skewY(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="second"><p>Div 1</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ek5gmoLv/)

CSS:

```
.se-slope{
    background: #47650a;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);

}

.se-slope {
    margin: 0 -50px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    -ms-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.se-content {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    color: #000;

   padding-top:120px;
   padding-bottom: 120px;
   margin-left: 10%;
   margin-right: 10%;

}

.above{
   background: #47650a;
   padding-bottom: 120px;
   width:100%;
}

.below
{
  background: gray;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  margin-top: -110px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="above">

 </div>
 <div class="se-slope">
        <article class="se-content">
          <p>You should use CSS TRANSFORM. That way you can do all kinds off neat stuff. Hav you tried skew allready? Or animations in JQuery build cool wepp apps. Be creative use arrows and circles...</p>
        </article>
</div>

 <div class="below">

 </div>
```